# overflow property in select tag

Tags: html, css

I can not get the overflow property to have any effect when used in a select tag. The enclosed code illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select size=5 style="overflow:auto">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the dropdown box to not have a vertical scrollbar in this case but it does.

The W3C Validator accepts the code segment, if that means anything, but I can't find any documentation that says whether this is a valid use of the overflow property.

Is this browser specific? If you run the code sample with or without the overflow porperty then Firefox and Chrome paint scrollbars but Opera doesn't. Again, can't find any documentation that discusses this.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns are specific elements, which are rendered differently from browser to browser. If you want to  apply custom styles consistently and like you're used to, you can replace it with a normal div, for example using this plugin: http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/

Answer (score 0):

I've found an article -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms

which states that you can't style a select element. That's not strictly true but it may explain why the overflow property has no effect.